# iPhone Urban Airship Crash InstanceNotExitsts

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, push, urbanairship.com

So, I followed UA documentation and got everything working good. The issues is I keep getting this crash below.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InstanceNotExists', reason: 'Attempted to access instance before initializaion. Please call takeOff: first.'
```

It only seems to happen if you open the app close it then try and reopen it, or if you open the app close the app, send a notification and then try and click on the notification. It never crashes on first load. Code that I have installed below.

```
#import "UAirship.h"
#import "UAPush.h"

 -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
NSMutableDictionary *takeOffOptions = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[takeOffOptions setValue:launchOptions forKey:UAirshipTakeOffOptionsLaunchOptionsKey];

[UAirship takeOff:takeOffOptions];

// Register for notifications
[[UAPush shared]
 registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];


-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
 //Updates the device token and registers the token with UA.
 NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
 [[UAPush shared] registerDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}

-(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
 {
  // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
 [UAirship land];
 [self saveContext];
```

}

Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks